# Why do I get 'this field is required' error in Django models, is there error in my code?

Tags: django

So I am trying to make User form where A user can Upload picture using File-field in models. I am choosing a picture still it says this field is required (after submiting the form) and unloads the pic.

models.py:

```
# These are our database files for the Incubator Portal
class Incubators(models.Model):
    incubator_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    owner = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    city_location = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    logo = models.FileField()
    verify = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('main:details', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

incubator-form.html

```
<form method="post" novalidate>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I have added the following code in site's main urls.py:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

And added the following to settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

I have even created media folder in the project directory. I have another class with same FileField which works fine. The problem is only in this class.

Comment: Can you post the form class?

Comment: And it may be better if you can post the error

Comment: I have posted the form class. As for the error, I just get this error message "No field is selected" when I click submit after hitting submit (It simply does not take the image)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an `enctype` attribute on your form tag, which means that the file upload will never reach Django. From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads):

> Note that `request.FILES` will only contain data if the request method was POST and the `<form>` that posted the request has the attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. Otherwise, request.FILES will be empty.

You need to update your form tag like so:

```
<form method="post" novalidate enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```